# Why functions are returned from angular services

Tags: angularjs

While defining a angular services, one is expected to pass a Constructor function. This constructor function would be initialized using "new" keyword and the object returned by "new" is set to the service.   so far so good.

However often I come across instances where programmers are creating services as below:

```
app.service('aObj', function AClass(){

  return function(a,b){
    alert(a + b);
  };

});
```

This would be called as

```
aObj(1,2)
```

Although I undertsand that aObj will now end up being a function, I cannot understand why programmers initialize their services this way. Constructor functions usually would have a definition like:

```
app.service('aObj', function AClass(){

  this.var1 = undefined;
  this.calculate = function(b){
    alert(this.var1 + b);
  };

});
```

Then eventually one would call this as 
    aObj.var1 = 1;
    aObj.calculate(2);

Can someone elaborate on the purpose of defining services using the former method ?

```
Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:FrTqqTNoY8BEfHs9bB0f
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on what kind of API you want to expose from your service.

Return an object and call them as `MyService.methodA()` and `MyService.methodB()` if the service is a container for exposing several closely related methods. Angular's [`$location service`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) is an example of this.

If the service exposes only a single public method, then it can be more convenient for users of the service to call it as `MyService()` rather than `MyService.theOnlyMethod()`. Angular's [`$compile service`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#usage) is an example of this.